# Bluetooth communication on tensorflow-lite android

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am implementing an android app for running the TensorFlow-lite classification model.

Now I'd like to make the app to send the signal when a certain class is detected.

**Is there any built-in module in TensorFlow or TensorFlow-lite?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no communication modules in the TensorFlow Lite product.   Instead, check out the Android Bluetooth API.